# gfortran compiler on windows powershell not creating executable

Tags: windows, powershell, fortran

The title says it all really, I run gfortran to compile a simple test fortran program, it compiles with no errors; but when I run ls to look at the output, there is no executable created. I've tried with the -o option set as well.

[image]

The fotran program is a simple hello world

```
program test1
implicit none
print *, "Hello World!"
end program test1
```

(The gfortran I'm using is from the mingw release; I have aliased gfortran to c:/mingw/bin/gfortran.exe within powershell, but the same problem happens if I call it explicitly)

Has anyone had this problem before? I thought it might be a permissions issue but I can create files from powershell just fine (unless gfortran needs additional permissions for some reason?). Any help greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You specify that it does not work from PowerShell but have you tried from the command prompt yet? That should help narrow down if the shell is the issue or not.

Comment: Did you look for a.exe ?

Comment: That's very strange. I have gfortran 5.1.0 from the TDM-GCC-32 package installed and tried to replicate your problem locally. Running `gfortran .\test1.f95`, I get `a.exe` in the local directory compiling under both `cmd.exe` and PowerShell. If you had a permissions issue, I would expect something to complain about not being able to write `a.exe`. I suspect an issue with environment variables but that's just a guess. Try doing a disk search for `a.exe` - can you find the file anywhere?

Comment: I'm using 6.3.0. Looks like a gcc, g++ and gfortran all exhibit the same problem: creates a.exe from cmd prompt but not from powershell.  Had look using process monitor (windows equivalent of strace). it is not launching ld.exe, which explains why it does not create a.exe.

Comment: If you check $env:path, is the mingw bin directory, on it?

Comment: Sorry it's been a while, I forgot I was having this issue. cup's comment basically got it, I've posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

Turns out simply aliasing the path to the compiler doesn't work in powershell for MinGW, adding the mingw bin directory to the path is necessary and solved my problem as @cup suggested in the comments. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score -1):

I just happened to have the same problem that you described but two years later ...

[image]

I found that I just need to call the program as **./test.exe** instead of **test.exe**, as I would have done with MS-DOS. That way I do not have to change the path if I work in a different folder.